# Coding on multiple machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization

What methods would you use to securely use multiple machines to work on code in active development?

#### My Ideal Situation

- Sharing development code securely among multiple machines (at least two)
- Automatic synchronization (think Google docs whereby any user's changes update all the others immediately). The reason for this is that I'd like to be able to use these computers interchangeably without having to  commit / clone every time I switch. My understanding is that automatic synchronization would make it possible to switch machines seamlessly without having to commit a bunch of files each time.
- The location of the development code is such that it can be accessed by a local Rails server and rendered on `localhost:3000`.
- The solution works for Apple machines (both my computers are Apple).

I'm not sure if this question is a 'reasonable' question in terms of its specificity but it's the best first attempt I have. Thanks!

Comment: Why does code need active synchronization?  Why not just use distributed version control?

Comment: @robert - I'm barely more than a beginner with git, but it seems to me that doing commits every time I want to switch machines then cloning the code would be quite a pain (it doesn't work well for doing some desktop work in the morning, then grabbing the laptop and working outside for an hour or two, then returning).

Comment: yep u can use git for example...it will not be a pain at all..it is only few seconds to pull and push changes

Comment: do you sync over the internet or are the computers on the same network? otherwise ... just use rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the only person working on this project, then a service like [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) would work and provide you with the automatic synchronisation you're after.

However, if you're working with someone else on this project, or you're likely to do so in the future, then it's worth learning the basics of Git (or some other distributed version control system).  It's probably not as hard as you expect:

- You can get by with a few basic commands (see [Everyday Git with 20 commands or so](http://schacon.github.com/git/everyday.html)).
- You can simplify things even further with [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) (this isn't perfect, but in most cases it makes fetching remote changes into a single command).
- There are various OS X GUIs available to help you, including [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) and [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/)
- You can get private repository hosting from [GitHub (for a small fee)](http://github.com/plans) or from [butbucket (for free)](https://bitbucket.org/plans).

Syncing with Git won't be automatic, but it does give you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

use any version control system (guess you do already) and if you really need automatic synchronisation put something like this in your crontab (assuming svn and growl for notifications):

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/checkout; svn update && svn commit -m '' || (echo "sync failed" |growlnotify )
```

I think version control is safest best practice for code sharing.

If it is only you working on the code, you can certainly set up another mode of syncing like auto-sync dropbox folder.

Also, if the assumption is you always got your laptop accessible as well when working on desktop, you could just use the actual laptop's code location as a shared network folder on your desktop, so no syncing is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is the best free and easy solution. I use it as well for my personal projects. Only beware to run dropbox on two computers at once when from one pc you sending changes and second one is only running dropbox, you propably loose your work(that was my case).